# messageCompose problem in recipients

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm assining a `NSMutableArray` called "arrmIndexArray" to the property recipients of MFMessageComposeViewController like:

```
contoller.recipients=arrmIndexArray
```

But its crashing.

```
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]){ 
    NSLog(@"contact page MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText");
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self

    NSLog(@"get sms etxt is %@",[msmscheck getsmsText]);
    controller.body =[msmscheck getsmsText];

    NSLog(@"agter the getsms text");


    NSLog(@"arr-- from server-->%@",arrmIndexArray);

    //Crashes on this line:
    controller.recipients = arrmIndexArray;


    NSLog(@"recipent---%@",controller.recipients);
    NSString *messag=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"message sent to %d people",[arrmIndexArray count]];
    controller.editing = NO;

    summary=messag;
    NSLog(@"before--");
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"after-");
    [controller release];
}
```

giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: What is this line `arrayWithObjects:@"8147042736",nil]`?

Comment: How were you able to compile this code? It won't even compile.

Comment: thais is commented line.now removed

Answer (score 0):

You should look at apples docunents about MFMailComposer. You should be using

```
- (void)setToRecipients:(NSArray*)toRecipients
```

to set the recipients. 
MFMailComposer Class Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html
MFMailComposer sample project: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008865

Comment: its solved now.some memory release problem was there,and secondlly there array i converted into string using string with format then passed iton reciepint,